# React Router path wrongly matches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React v4.2 for my app, and it seems not to be matching the correct path for the routes:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" render={(props) => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                  return <Redirect to='/' />;
                } else {
                  return <LoginForm {...props}/>
                }
              }
            } />
            <EnsureLoggedInContainer>
              <Route exact path="/group" render={(props) => {
                debugger;
                return <GroupList {...props}/>
              }
              }/>
              <Route exact path="/group/new" render={(props) => {
                debugger;
                return <GroupList {...props} modal={rr}/>;
              }
              } />
            </EnsureLoggedInContainer>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

I have some links in the app, on which I click and I redirect the client to new URL:

```
  _onSubmit(values) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    this.props.createGroup(values, ({status}) => history.push('/group'));
  }
```

I inspect the values of `props.history.location.pathname` and `props.match.path` and they don't match. Why is this happening? Why is the correct route not matched?

**Update 1**

The code for `EnsureLoggedInContainer`:

```
class EnsureLoggedInContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      dispatch(setRedirectUrl(currentURL))
      this.props.history.replace("/login")
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      return(
        <div>
          <AppNavBar />
          <ComponentsNavBar />
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <noscript />;
    }
  }
}

export default EnsureLoggedInContainer;
```

**Update 2**

I changed the router configuration code to the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                  return <Redirect to='/' />;
                } else {
                  return <LoginForm {...props}/>
                }
              }
            } />
            <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                  return <Redirect to='/' />;
                } else {
                  return <RegisterForm {...props}/>
                }
              }
            } />
            <EnsureLoggedInContainer>
              <Route exact path="/group" component={GroupList} modal={newGroupModal}/>
              <Route exact path="/group/new" component={GroupList}/>
              <Route component={Home} />
            </EnsureLoggedInContainer>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

And changed the last line of `EnsureLoggedInContainer` to :

```
export default withRouter(EnsureLoggedInContainer);
```

But still, I get `Home` always being rendered, and random URLs being matched to unrelated routes (e.g. `/group/new`)

Comment: Could you provide a code sample using codesandbox.io?

Comment: can you add what what you have written for EnsureLoggenInContainer component

Comment: @ShreyKejriwal I added the code, it seems that it is related. But I don't know how it could cause this issue.

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. Your EnsureLoggedInContainer is executed immediately when the page loads and your appnavbar and componentsnavbar is not rendered. We usually use HOC to guard the components. Exact errors can be found once you host your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve the issue by using the [private route pattern](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation:

> A `match` object contains information about how a  matched
>   the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> ```
> params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path
>
> isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
>
> path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested <Route>s
>
> url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested <Link>s
> ```

while

> Locations represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or
>   even where it was.

so if you are on say `/group/new`, `location.pathname` will give you `/group/new` whereas `match.path` will give your the Route path defined for the component in which you log it if it is matched

Comment: Try and Wrap EnsureLoggedInContainer with withRouter

Comment: Didn't work, please see my second Update in the original post.